# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Can I use a parameter for a table name?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I have a report that pulls from a SQL server database. The current FROM looks like

```
from wrapuptime 
inner join 
[iData3].[dbo].[N158] on [iData3].[dbo].[N158].AGENTNAME = wrapuptime.Agentname
```

I want to paramatise this report so that I can have multiple Idata3 tables and pull from different ones depending on which option the person running te report picks.

I have tried creating a parameter called teamleader and having the Value field as

```
="[idata3].[dbo].[N241847]"
```

with the code becoming

```
from wrapuptime 
    inner join 
    (@Teamleader) on (@Teamleader).AGENTNAME = wrapuptime.Agentname
```

but this doesn't work. Have I messed up the syntax or is this not possible. Thanks.

EDIT :

After a helpful comment below I went through the dynamic SQL tutorial and ended up with the following code

```
DECLARE 
    @table NVARCHAR(128),
     @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @table = N'idata3.dbo.N241847';
    SET @sql = N'





select 
distinct callref , 
actid,
--[StartTime],
[StartTime] as [StartTime],
convert(date,format([StartTime],''dd/MM/yyyy''),103) as [Date],
 Calltype,
 inbtot As [Inbound Time],

actTime-(inbtot+IsNull(outtime,0)) as [WrapTime],



outtime,
 wrapuptime.Agentname,
 Agent_Site,
 Client_name, 
 Teamleader

from wrapuptime 
inner join ' +
@Table + ' on ' + @table+'.AGENTNAME = wrapuptime.Agentname
LEFT JOIN 
inboundcallsview ON [wrapuptime].[callref]  = inboundcallsview.[Reference] 

where [StartTime] between ''2019-07-01'' and ''2019-07-07''

--Where StartTime between DATEADD(d, -1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE())) and DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GETDATE()))



and Agent_Site = ''Nottingham''



AND [account] IN (

SELECT Accountnumber from idata3.dbo.[N242024]

)


order by starttime'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Which despite being a huge mess **does work perfectly in SSMS**.

However when I copy and paste it into my query window in report builder 3.0 and hit Run to test it I get the option to put in a value for @table and when I do I get the following error message

[image: error]

I thought the DECLARE at the top would have sorted this issue. Am I now missing something regarding the transfer of the query from SSMS to RB 3.0?

Comment: I believe you would need to change the stored procedure to be dynamic to allow parameters of the table names.

Comment: @WEI_DBA if you could ELI5 as an answer I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: For starters, take the working stored procedure and start to paramertise it and making it dynamic. Start here... http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-dynamic-sql/

Comment: @WEI_DBA feels like I'm close. Got it to work in SSMS now the problem is with getting it into report builder.

Comment: Call the stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally get the data from the 'dynamic' table into a temp table and then the rest of the dataset query does not need to change.

For example something like this.

```
/* uncomment for testing - comment these two lines in SSRS dataset query
DECLARE @schemaName varchar(256) = 'dim'
DECLARE @tableName varchar(256) = 'country'
*/

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #t
CREATE TABLE #t (ColID int, ColName varchar(75), ColAnother varchar(20)) -- <= this should be able to handle any of your dynamic tables

SET @sql  = 'INSERT INTO #t SELECT CountryID, CountryDesc, CountryCode FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)

EXEC (@sql)

SELECT * 
    FROM MyOthertable a
       JOIN #t t on a.CountryID = t.ColID
```

In the example above I'm just doing some dynamic sql to populate the temp table and then I use the temp table in the main part of the query. Just make sure your query that populates the temp table always returns the same data types as the temp table.

Comment: When I use the code DECLARE [at]tableName varchar(256) 
SET [at]tableName = 'idata3.dbo.N241847'; I get the error Invalid object name 'idata3.dbo.N241847'  (I used [at] instead of @ in this comment)

Comment: removed QUOTENAME and it worked. No idea why but I'm going with it.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end, QUOTENAME will put `[ ]` around the name that's all, which would be needed if the table name had spaces in etc. If you had the schema AND table name in the table name variable then it would not work as it would wrap the whole thing in square brackets.
If this answered your question could you please mark the answer as accepted.